# Can't hook up IBOutlet or IBAction to a View Controller written in Swift after deleting the ObjC version

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, xcode6

I created a project in XCode 5 and imported it to XCode 6 beta, then later decided that I wanted to rewrite one of the ViewControllers in Swift. So I first deleted the controller file (both .h & .m) and added the same class named controller within a Swift file extension. Now when I try to hook up an outlet and action from the Storyboard by ctrl-dragging from the widget to the file, I can't create new connections.

Is this a bug or do I need to do something else to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be bug in Xcode 6. You can resolve this by Changing the ViewController Custom class in the identity inspector to some another class press return and again change the class to original class you want then press return.

Comment: When doing so in File's Owner of the xib, I needed to define the Module as well, in order to make it work.

Comment: Yes you should provide appropriate module(By default it identify the module).

Comment: I did noticed the File's owner thingie and changed it. This seems to work now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Defining the Module helped me. I had two targets in my project and had to pick the right one.